# angular get запрос не отправляет запрос на сервер, а пытается открыть страницу, почему?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, angular

```
    getHTTP(url) {
    console.log('Sended');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.get(url, {headers: httpOptions.headers, responseType: 'text'})
      .subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data);
        resolve(data);
      }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
        console.log("Error", error);
      });
    });
  }
```

Эта конструкция должна по логике отправлять запрос на сервер,
в компоненте вызываю этот метод:

```
    async getLeadList() {
    await this.myHttp.getHTTP('/getLeadList');
  }
```

На сервере ловлю запрос, и проверяю дошло ли обычным консол логом(Node.js),

```
router.get('/getLeadList', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    db.Lead.find({}).then(function(leads) {
        console.log(leads);
        res.status(200).send(leads);
    });
});
```

По итогу он не отправляет запрос на сервер, а пытается открыть передаваемый URL (http://localhost:4200/getLeadList).

```
HttpResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:3000/getLeadList", ok: true, …}
```

Почему он не отправляет запрос на сервер?

Я нашел проблему, она заключается в том, что мой nodejs обрабатывает все запросы и ссылается на корневую дирректорию ангуляр.

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/cleanupCRM/index.html'));
});
```

Если ее убрать, то запрос доходит до сервера, но при обновлении страниц (при нажатии f5) он будет выдавать ошибку

```
Cannot GET /someurl
```

на любой странице.

Как найти в этом компромисс?

Comment: Как это *а пытается открыть передаваемый URL*? Что это значит?

Comment: Это значит, что get запрос, не доходит до сервера, тк на сервере при этом гет запросе, в самом начале у меня стоит обычный console.log('some msg'), subscribe возвращает мне HttpResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "http://localhost:3000/getLeadList", ok: true, …}

Comment: так а console.log(data); что выводит?

Comment: console.log(data) выводит HttpResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: "localhost:3000/getLeadList", ok: true, …}, 
я нашел место в своем коде, где происходит ошибка, но эта строка важна для полноценной работы angular на nodejs.
Я дополнил свой изначальный пост

Comment: какая версия ангуляра? возможно у response надо сначала json вызвать

Comment: а, увидел, тогда вопрос что за app, и почему для апи у тебя router а не тот же app?

Comment: Потому что все routes выведены в отдельный файл. Я решил проблему, спасибо вам за ваши ответы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я решил проблему, спасибо всем и моему потраченному времени (15 часов).

Проблема заключается в следующем.
Не нужно вставлять заголовки для отправки get запроса, тк это добавляет в ответ ненужные строки кода, которые после нужно обрабатывать.
У меня был обработчик любого get запроса на моем nodejs

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/cleanupCRM/index.html'));
});
```

, который стоял до основного, который должен был обработать мой get(/getLeadList)

```
router.get('/getLeadList', function(req, res) {
    console.log('Дошло');
    db.Lead.find({}).then(function(leads) {
        console.log(leads);
        res.send(leads);
    });
});



app.use('/', router);
```

Последовательность была такая:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/cleanupCRM/index.html'));
});
app.use('/', router);
```

В этой последовательности и была проблема.
Необходимо поменять последовательность, где изначально обрабатываются мои запросы которые я обработал, а после обработка всех остальных.

```
app.use('/', router);
app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/dist/cleanupCRM/index.html'));
});
```